# Merging two arrays into one that has the same amount of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

need help with little thing. I've searched current question, but didn't find good example.

I have two arrays with same count of objects:

```
array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Johnny'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mike'}];
array2 = [{ hair: 'black'}, { hair: 'white'}];
```

I need

```
array3 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Johnny', hair: 'black'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Mike', hair: 'white'}
]
```

I've tried several ways with push and [...ES6], but I always return 4 objects instead of 2.

Comment: so object's properties at the same index in two different arrays should be merged?

Comment: yes, same index objects return one object with merged keys and values

Answer (score 5):

Use Object.assign of ES6:

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Johnny'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mike'}];
var array2 = [{ hair: 'black'}, { hair: 'white'}];
var merged = array1.map((el, index) => Object.assign(el, array2[index]));
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds

Comment: Thank you! that's was I've looking for.

Comment: @AlekseyTrofimenko Don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for an arbitrary count of arrays and map objects at same index in one object.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Johnny'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mike'}];
    array2 = [{ hair: 'black'}, { hair: 'white'}],
    result = [array1, array2]
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((o, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, o), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```